# post data with value showing valid response data but same value from regular expression is not showing valid response data in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

When manually entering value in below parameters, it's working fine and showing a valid response.

Below post shows data when values are manually entered:
`POST https://qatbagp523.unix.gsm1900.org/wcs/resources/store/11151/quoteHandler/syncQuote`

```
POST data:
{
  "opportunityId":"92456",
  "quoteNumber":"54044"
}
```

[no cookies]

But same value captured from regular expression will not show valid response data

Below post data values captured from regular expression
POST `https://qatbagp523.unix.gsm1900.org/wcs/resources/store/11151/quoteHandler/syncQuote`

```
POST data:
{
  "opportunityId":"92456",
  "quoteNumber":"54044"
}
```

[no cookies]

Even same post data values but manually entered post data is showing valid response but regular expression captured post data is not showing valid response
I observed headers and other valuesm there is no change, could any please resolve how to get response and what could be the cause for this type of issues

Comment: Can you share the configuration steps, of regular expression and Http request data you have passed by configuring regular expression values.

Comment: I am taking only one request but value passing manual entered,it generates response data, but value generated by regular expression(same value it captures and passing it into payload you can observe above, there is no difference in payload for both manually entered and regular expression passing value), system not showing valid response for regular expression generated value request...please let me what could be the reason

Comment: Please note same request there is no confusion in headers and other values...

Answer (score 0):

Given you send the same requests you should be getting the same responses, if you have different responses - most probably you're sending different requests

1. Compare 2 requests using [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener, they should be exactly the same in terms of request body, request headers, etc.
2. Check the variable which is stored by the Regular Expression Extractor using [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler), it might the case there are extra spaces, line breaks, etc.
3. Use a third-party external sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) or [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) as View Results Tree listener doesn't always tell the full story

If you won't be able to figure out the root cause of the issue - consider [saving all the request and response data for both Samplers](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-save-response-data-in-jmeter) and update your question with the XML file containing these details.